# What files would I be able to view as localhost?

Tags: permissions

If I was able to view any page on a website as localhost using SSRF, what files should I check for? I checked to see if I could view robots.txt normally, and I couldn't, but using SSRF, I was able to. What other files are typical on websites that are normally hidden to the public, but would be visible on the localhost?

Comment: I think robots.txt should be publicly accessible regardless, otherwise how would search engine spiders read it?

Comment: @thexacre that's what I thought, but I guess this isn't the case. I've found this on two websites. One being Facebook-Studio. I reported it to Facebook and they fixed the issue.

Comment: I can access the robots.txt on that site publicly, but perhaps they fixed it because of other implications - which is I suppose why you asked this question :P

Answer (score 1):

In a Microsoft environment, your best bet is probably the trace.axd file.  This is often enabled and is set to local only so you would be able to access it from localhost.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386420%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This tracing info can include lots of debugging material, developer output and environment configuration data.

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately I got a 404 for that file, but I found out that cgi-sys folder exists, so I'm assuming they're using Cpanel.